# Load next and previous page on ListView Scroll in android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments, pagination

[image: response from webservice]I am creating a ListView in which I am fetching news from server. And I am getting data page wise i.e. at one time I got one page with 10 items. On down scroll I  am hitting that web service again and get next page data to be shown but problem is that suppose I have total 22 items on server and in first attempt I got 22 to 13 then 12 to 3 after that when it comes to last 2 data web service hits again and again. I don't know why web service hit again and again when there is only 2 data. And I don't how to load previous page.

**code for the same**

```
       listNews.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {




        }

        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                             int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            Log.e(TAG, "onScroll: "+firstVisibleItem +" "+visibleItemCount+" "+totalItemCount );
            if(firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount == totalItemCount && totalItemCount!=0)
            {

                callNewsApi((Integer.parseInt(currentPage)+1)+"");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: add your response

Comment: maybe this https://guides.codepath.com/android/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView will help. Also debugging with logs should help

Comment: I hope , this http://www.devexchanges.info/2015/03/android-listview-dynamically-load-more.html will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to validate the last page after each hit response. Better way to do it on server site . But you can also manage it at client end . below is an example .

```
 private boolean isLastPage;
private int PER_PAGE_COUNT=10;
//@params size- size of data which you get form server each time hit i shoule <= PER_PAGE_COUNT
public void validateLastpage(int size) {
    if(size==0){
        isLastPage=true;
    }else {
        if (size % PER_PAGE_COUNT == 0) {
            isLastPage = false;
        } else {
            isLastPage = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Now check for **isLastPage** on each hit. This will stop your extra network called after no more data at server site.
Call **validateLastpage(int size)** after each response with new data size .
On each pagination check for last page .

```
 public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                     int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onScroll: "+firstVisibleItem +" "+visibleItemCount+" "+totalItemCount );
    if (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount == totalItemCount && totalItemCount != 0) {
        if(!isLastPage)
        callNewsApi((Integer.parseInt(currentPage) + 1) + "");
    }
}
```