# Load page on scroll up ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, scroll, pagination

I am working on an app in which I want to load previous and next page on scroll up and down of ListView respectively. I am able to implement scroll down functionality and successfully load next page but I am not able to load previous page on scroll up.

In my app, I don't save ListView items. I just load data on basis of page and show in list.

**Code for the same**

```
listNews.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {}

    private int lastVisibleItem = 0;
    private int lastY = 0;

    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                         int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        int top = 0;
        if (view.getChildAt(0) != null) {
            top = view.getChildAt(0).getTop();
        }

        Log.e(TAG, "onScroll: " + firstVisibleItem + " " + visibleItemCount + " " + totalItemCount);

        // code for scroll down and load next page
        if (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount == totalItemCount && totalItemCount != 0 && !next_page_url.equals("null")) {
            callNewsApi((Integer.parseInt(currentPage) + 1) + "");
        }

        // code for scroll up and load previous page but not work
        else if (firstVisibleItem <= lastVisibleItem && !prev_page_url.equals("null")) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onScrollup: ");
            //callNewsApi((Integer.parseInt(currentPage) - 2) + "");
            //scroll up
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Do not put same question twice. You have already ask similar paging question .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load next and previous page on ListView Scroll in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47806311/load-next-and-previous-page-on-listview-scroll-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the visible list View items and based on the past and the present visible item you can determine whether its scroll up or down and implement your adding page function.

Answer (score 0):

change the below line

```
else if(firstVisibleItem <= lastVisibleItem && !prev_page_url.equals("null")){
```

to

```
else if(firstVisibleItem == 0 && !prev_page_url.equals("null")){
```

as you might be changing your lastVisibleItem value somewhere in your code. Try this if it doesnt work the try to check if !prev_page_url.equals("null") condition is true or not

Comment: If I use this condition then it hits api again and again as firstVisibleItem is 0 many times

Comment: You can also use pull to refresh listener to prevent this issue that will resolve this and works proper for overscrolling up for listview

Comment: or else if you dont want to create swipeRefresh the you can create your own linear layout let me know if you want to create 1